# Is Hask locally small?

Tags: haskell

Is the category Hask of haskell objects an example of a locally small category?

http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+small+category

Maybe not..  hask as cpo
http://www.cs.gunma-u.ac.jp/~hamana/Papers/cpo.pdf

The haskellwiki, http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hask has very good information, showing that Hask is not Cartesian Closed.

Comment: Haskell has that uncomfortable "polymorphism" thing that ruins most nice size properties. So my guess is "no" -- but I'm not enough of an expert to make that into a real counterexample!

Comment: The reason I'm asking is due to a conversation on reddit dealing with the correct interpretation in haskell of n-ary functors. [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1bg21c/so_i_accidentally_a_profunctors_tutorial/c96kvf8)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24540/is-the-presheaf-category-of-a-locally-small-category-locally-small  This question may be related.

Comment: the category Set is not small.

Answer (score 2):

What is Hask?  If it includes all the haskell definable "functions" as morphism then definitly not

```
data Big = Big (Big -> Big)
```

the "hom set" of `Big -> Big` contains the entire untyped lambda calculus!  I doubt it is locally small even if you only allow terminating functions--I think there are no set theoretic models of system-f.

EDIT: seven years later I can't make heads or tails of what I was trying to say here. Hask has no set theoretic models, in the sense of models which interpret function types as the full sets of functions. That is true, but I don't know what that has to do with the question. It isn't really clear what "Hask" is, but any reasonable answer seems to me would have small homsets (that is, it *is* locally small).

The strangeness of my answer from many years past is slightly embarrassing to me. I'm sure I meant something very insightful--I just have no idea what that was, and as worded it seems *rather wrong*.

Comment: Found a comment here,[link] (http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/01/topos_theory_can_make_you_a_pr.html#c036643) on building a set-theoretic model of system-f

Comment: @edeast that is interesting.  I think I was remembering this http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/07/62/61/PDF/RR-0296.pdf paper

Comment: Your source may be more authoritative than mine. Dan Doel does forsee problems in the modeling effort. "because, what the hell is a uniform family of set theoretic functions?"

Comment: Is it actually the case that if there is no set-theoretic model, then the collection of all terms cannot be a set? That isn't obvious to me; the property of being a *model* imposes greater structure than the property of merely having all the terms.

Comment: @DanielWagner I answered this question 7 years ago, and, honestly, am not sure what I meant to say here.

The categories of CPOs is, obviously, locally small. As is the term model. What you can't have is a (non trivial) model which interprets function types as the full set of functions, since there are no non trivial solutions to T = T^T in Set.

Comment: I'm half way inclined to delete this answer just because, if I can't understand what I was saying, I don't see how it is plausible that anyone else could

Answer (score 1):

Hask objects are Haskell types which are countably infinite. Hask arrows are Haskell functions which are also countably infinite. Therefore Hask is not only locally small, Hask is small.

card(ob(Hask))=card(hom(Hask))=card(N)

More details about Hask here:

http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Category-Theory-Presentation/

Comment: um...that is not how it works.  The fact that all programs are finite does not make the universe of programs countable.  Skolem's paradox here.

Comment: @PhilipJF, I have constructed a model obeying this as an answer.  I'd like your feedback about where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Especially @PhillipJF, here's a try.  I'm not trying to make the most accurate or elegant model of Hask, I'm just trying to make *a* model.  Critique, please.

If A is a Haskell type, define a *value of type A* in Hask to be an equivalence class of well-typed Haskell terms of type A (strings x for which `x :: A` would be accepted by the type checker), modulo extensional equality.  That is, two terms are considered equal if they expand out to the same (possibly infinite) normal form, and two terms which have no hnf are also equal.  The fact that this is not decidable is irrelevant, we need only state these conditions set-theoretically, which I have little doubt we can do.

Let the objects of **Hask** be Haskell types (primitive types & user-defined types; we will assume that all user-definable types exist and have distinct names.  User-defined type definitions are source code, so they are countable.  Just name them `D0`,`D1`, ... according to that counting.).

Let the morphisms *A -> B* be values of type *A -> B*

Let the identity on *A* be the equivalence class of `id :: A -> A`, and similarly let composition of `g` and `f` be the equivalence class of `g . f`.

The set of all values is a countable set, because terms are just strings over a finite alphabet.  So this model of **Hask** is small.

Is this wrong?

Comment: This is this thing that always happens.  Since syntax is finite (for every logic), stuff like this should just work.  The problem is that you run into paradox.  Like, consider the hom set `Nat -> Bool`.  Suppose you had a function `f :: Nat -> Nat -> Bool` which generated each haskell program corresponding to a member of this hom set (allowing repetition).  Then we could define `g n = not (f n n)` which is clearly not something this generates.  This is why Skolem's paradox is a paradox! see http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/more-is-not-always-better/ for similar ideas

Comment: @PhilipJF, it is not computable for `f` to generate all and only the total functions, so it must generate some partial programs, i.e. some n such that `f n n = _|_`.  The thing is, `_|_` is a fixed point of `not`, so `not (f n n)`  "is clearly not something this generates" is false.  I agree that this is subtle and paradoxical-seeming territory if not approached with rigor (and it still makes my brain explode from time to time).  I wrote a koan about this: cf. http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/computably-uncountable/

Comment: [Link](http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/msg53027.html)  an interpretation of Luke Palmer's result from Haskell cafe, by Ryan Ingram

Comment: I think it boils down to if church's law is true luqui's model of Hask = PCF = small?   Wheras church's law being false may imply something else entirely."  
ffr; Robert Harper's " Practical Foundations for Programming Languages" chap 9, 10.  and the relevant blog posts

Comment: Are you just riffing now, or does this have some bearing on the original question?

Comment: Ya just riffing,  working my way through stuff, will delete the comments later.