# Why is it fair to think of just locally small cartesian closed categories in Haskell for the Curry class?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, currying, category-theory

[`Control.Category.Constrained`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html) is a very interesting project that presents the class for cartesian closed categories - [`Curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Curry).

Yet, I do not see why we think of all cartesian closed categories which allow `curry` and `uncurry` (`Hom(X * Y, Z) ≅ Hom(X, Z^Y)` in terms of category theory). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category#Definition) says that such property holds only for locally small cartesian closed categories. Under [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775646/is-hask-locally-small) many people suggest that **Hask** itself is not locally small (on the other hand, everyone says that [**Hask** is not a cartesian closed category](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask#Hask_is_not_Cartesian_closed), which I reckon to be pure and uninteresting formalism).

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2369694/766593) on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) speaks on assuming all categories are locally small. But it is given from a mathematical point of view where we discuss properties. I would like to know why we decided to concentrate on `curry` and `uncurry` as [`Curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:Curry)’s methods. Is it because pretty much everyone who knows Haskell also knows these functions? Or is there any other reason?

Comment: IMO, this kinds of questions can never be completely answered. **Hask** isn't a rigorous mathematical construction, but more of a name for "some category of types and functions" defined in vague terms, and with a good dose of hand-waving. It _is_ useful in programming, but (IMO) not as much when we move to math/theoretical CS. Andrej Bauer is against **Hask**, claiming that is has no place in math, and it's better to use a well-known category like wCPO or PERs. I have no idea on how to fully interpret Haskell there, though.

Comment: @chi the question is not about **Hask** itself - it is about the interface we chose for Control.Category.Constrained.Curry. I should probably change the wording of the question.

Comment: It is also my opinion that non-locally small CCCs are not very interesting as a model of computation. In programming we can only define countably many functions -- I can understand if in the model the cardinality gets higher, but (IMO) having a proper class is way too much.

Comment: @chi I guess that might be the reason. I would appreciate if You write an answer which explains why we favour locally small cartesian closed categories that much.

Comment: Are you sure that Hask is not locally small? The arguments at your link that it is don't seem super convincing to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner I wrote “some people suggest…” - I really do not know. It was just a link I decided to put into the post - it seems in its place :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to know why we decided to concentrate on `curry` and `uncurry` as `Curry`’s methods. Is it because pretty much everyone who knows Haskell also knows these functions?

As the library author I can answer that with confidence and the answer is **yes**: it is because `curry` and `uncurry` are well-established part of the Haskell vernacular. `constrained-categories` was never intended to radically change Haskell and/or make it more mathematically solid in some sense, but rather to subtly generalise the existing class hierarchies – mostly to allow defining functors etc. that couldn't be given `Prelude.Functor` instances.

Whether `Curry` could be formalised in terms of local smallness I frankly don't know. I'm also not sure whether that and other “maths foundations” aspects can even be meaningfully discussed in the context of a Haskell library. <sup><sub>***Somewhat off-topic rant ahead***</sub></sup> It's just a fact that Haskell is a non-total language, and yes, that means just about any axiom can be thwarted by some `undefined` attack. But I also don't really see that as a problem. Many people seem to think of Haskell as a sort of *uncanny valley*: too restrictive for use in real-world applications, yet nothing can be proved properly. I see it exactly the other way around: Haskell has a sufficiently powerful type system to be able to *express* the mathematical ideas that are useful for real-world applications, without getting its value semantics caught up too deep in the underlying foundations to be practical to actually use in the real world. (I.e., you don't constantly spend weeks proving some “obviously it's true that...” theorem. *I'm looking at you, Coq...*)
Instead of writing 100% rigorous proofs, we narrow down the types as best as possible and then use QuickCheck to see whether something *typically works* as the maths would demand.

Don't get me wrong, I think formalising the foundations is important too and dependently-typed total languages are great, but all that is somewhat missing the point of where Haskell's potential really lies. At least it's not where *I* aim my Haskell development, including `constrained-categories`. If somebody who's deeper into the pure maths wants to chime in, I'm delighted to hear about it.